# jQuery works from the Firebug console, but not on page load

Tags: jquery, firebug

I'm very new to jQuery and javascript in general, so maybe there's something I've missed.

I have a html page with a link to the latest version of jQuery in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But any jQuery code that I try to execute anywhere... in the head or a separate .js file, won't run when I load the page.  However normal javascript does.

Firebug acknowledges that the jQuery library has loaded when I click Script or Dom... the console will even accept and run my jQuery code with no hassles.

Here's the html... yes it is html5 and it works fine all browsers besides Opera and IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Produkshunator</title>   

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/skins.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/formlayout.css" />  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index4.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="vbox flex">

      <!-- header ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <header class="hbox">
            <div class="hbox flex" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                <img src="icons/Produkshunator.png" style="height:60px;width:490px;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="login_status" style="width:150px;"></div>  
        </header>

      <!-- body ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <div class="flex hbox">



<!-- Forms ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->              

                <section class="vbox right" style="width:400px; padding:0; overflow: visible;">

    <!-- Login Form ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->

                <form class="flex sleek"
                      name="login"
                      id="login">

                    <h2 class="r">Login</h2>

                    <div>   
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>                       
                         <input type="button" value="Submit" class="form_butt" />
                     </div>
                     <p><i id="log_error" class="error"></i></p>    
                </form>


    <!-- Registration Form ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->   

                <form class="sleek flex"
                      name="register"
                      id="register">
                    <h2 class="r">Register</h2>

                      <div>
                         <label>First Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" required="flag" name="firstname"/>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                         <label>Last Name:</label>
                         <input type="text" required="flag" name="lastname"/>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                         <label>Email:</label>
                         <input type="email" required="flag" name="email"/>
                      </div>
                      <div>   
                         <label>Password:</label>
                         <input type="password" required="flag" name="password"/>
                      </div>
                      <div>   
                         <label>Retype Password:</label>
                         <input type="password" required="flag" name="password2"/>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                          <input type="button" value="Submit" class="form_butt" />
                      </div>        
                      <p id="reg_error" class="error"></p>  
                </form>

            </section>

        </div> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

Is there something I need to know that isn't in the tutorials?

Comment: Can you either link to the page or post some HTML?  Also, you're probably better off using the Google APIs version of jQuery: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Thanks mway... just changed the jQuery link and posted up the html.

Comment: and what's inside `index4.js`?

Comment: PS, put a http:// in front of the Google APIs URL. :)

Comment: Eh... use an unordered list for your `label` - input` pairs. It's more semantic that way. Also, `label` tags require the `for` attributes for accessibility reasons.

Comment: @mway - maybe just a typo. OP's says `Firebug acknowledges that the jQuery library has loaded`.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - haha the OP has a greater problem than that. ;)

Comment: @Reigal Which is why it's a comment. And anyway, nothing wrong with picking on others code here, eh? Accessibility and semantics *are* important, just not entirely relevant for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    // Your code goes here    
});
```